# Group by, multiple count, multiple tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables as following:

First table: 2016

```
Os          |   Count
------------+----------
Windows 7         8
Windows 7         9
Windows 7        20
Windows 8        30
Linux            15
```

Second table: 2017

```
Os          |   Count
------------+----------
Windows 7        35
Windows 7        11
Windows 8        10
Windows 8         8
Linux            10
Ubuntu            3
```

I try by myself but my challenge is to use GROUP BY function in meanwhile I'm counting two fields from two different tables, I got always error.

Thank you in advance,

**Update:**

I'm sorry I did a mistake in explaining my request: what I need is to write a query to get a result like this:

```
    --OS--         --2016--    --2017--
    ------------------------------------
    Windows 7        37             46
    Windows 8        30             18
    Linux            15             10
    Ubuntu           0              3
```

Comment: You should edit your question and show the query you have tried.  Hint:  `UNION ALL` before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Or an `OUTER JOIN` might work if you want a single inner subquery without a union.

Answer (score 2):

Without a `UNION ALL` you can do this:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( [2016].[OS], [2017].[OS] ) AS [OS],
    ( [2016].[Count] + [2017].[Count] ) AS [Count]
FROM
    [2016]
    FULL OUTER JOIN [2017] ON [2016].[OS] = [2017].[OS]
```

This also eliminates the need for `GROUP BY` too, assuming the `OS` columns contain no duplicates.

Duplicates would need to be eliminated through `GROUP BY` (rather than `SELECT DISTINCT`), but the same structure applies:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( [2016-D].[OS], [2017].[OS] ) AS [OS],
    ( [2016-D].[Count] + [2017].[Count] ) AS [Count]
FROM
    (
        SELECT [OS], SUM( [Count] ) FROM [2016] GROUP BY [OS]
    ) AS [2016-D]
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [OS], SUM( [Count] ) FROM [2017] GROUP BY [OS]
    ) AS [2017-D]
        ON [2016].[OS] = [2017].[OS]
```

...but then it gets quite unwieldy, and the `UNION ALL` approach becomes simpler!

#### Update:

The OP has amended their question to say they want separate columns - so this is where using an `OUTER JOIN` becomes the ideal solution:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE( [2016-D].[OS], [2017-D].[OS] ) AS [OS],
    [2016-D].[Count] AS [2016],
    [2017-D].[Count] AS [2017]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            [OS],
            SUM( [Count] ) AS [Count]
        FROM
            [2016]
        GROUP BY
            [OS]
    ) AS [2016-D]
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            [OS],
            SUM( [Count] ) AS [Count]
        FROM
            [2017]
        GROUP BY
            [OS]
    ) AS [2017-D]
        ON [2016].[OS] = [2017].[OS]
ORDER BY
    [OS]
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just noticed the original data is non-unique, so yes, my answer is incorrect - unless there's another reason?

Comment: . . Nope.  That's the reason.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a version which eliminates duplicates.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I updated my question because I did a mistake at the beginning to explain how's the query I need. Can you please check it

Comment: @WaleedELerksosy See my revised answer.

Comment: Perfect, good job!, I just have to replace this line "ON [2016].[OS] = [2017].[OS]" with [2017-D].[OS] = [2016-D].[OS]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do simple group by as below:

```
select a.OS, sum(count) from (
    select * from your2016table
        union all 
    select * from your2017table
    ) a
    group by a.OS
```

For that you can use year as group by and pivot

```
;with cte as (
select a.OS, a.[year], SumCt = sum(count) from (
    select *, 2016 as [year] from your2016table
        union all 
    select *, 2017 as [year] from your2017table
    ) a
    group by a.OS, a.[year]
)
select * from cte 
pivot (max(sumct) for [year] in ([2016], [2017])) p
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I updated my question because I did a mistake explaining what I need, can you please check it